# CSS transformed object position fix

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

It was hard to explain with words, so I tried to explain with graphics.

There is a div here with its style.

[image]

Now if I change its width with 400px here...

[image]

because of it is a transformed (rotated) object, something happens and "TOP-LEFT" corner of it, moves down.

Now I want to keep its "TOP-LEFT" position fixed. But I couldnt find a correct correlation to fix it. I guess I need a trigonometric formula using rotation angle.

Also I know it is related with '`scale`' and '`transform-origin`' and can be easily done with them but I dont want to use any other transformation parameters. Especialy '`transform-origin`' because of lack of browser support.

Does anybody here who can help me with the correlation which will be used in JavaScript to fix its corner. Maybe `getBoundingClientRect()` can be used for this.

Here is the [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/y343Z/)

Thank you.

Comment: could you put this in a jsFiddle? we will have to check with multiple browsers i guess.

Comment: Here is the [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/y343Z/)

Comment: I don't get it, you don't want to transform the origin because of browser support, but surely all browsers that support transform rotate also supports transform-origin

Comment: @adeneo you are absolutely right. But It is not so hard to rotate objects from center point with older versions of IE. But if I mix transfrom origin it will not be so easy. Another and bigger reason is there are plenty of objects in DB which are saved with their position values calculated relative to their center.

Comment: transform-origin property is supported in Internet Explorer 10, Firefox, and Opera. for IE9 you can use -ms-transform-origin. And if you looking to provide support below than that, then i believe transform: rotate(45deg) won't work on that. so can easily use transform-origin for your use.

Answer (score 8):

CSS transforms are really matrices, where transforming the elements are done with
`matrix(a, b, c, d, tx, ty)`.

Then someone clever figured out it would be too complicated for webdesigners to understand such a matrix, so they added shorthand solutions, like `transform: rotate()` etc.

In other words, if you view the computed styles, there won't be a style whith the rotated degrees, and you can't do `element.style.transform` and get the rotation angle back again, all you'll get is the matrix.

Since the browsers use a matrix, all browsers that support CSS transform, also support changing the origin of that transform, so if you can rotate the element, you can change the origin.

The exception is Microsoft's filters, but even there you can rotate and change the origin, it's just a little more complicated to figure out.

As it makes no sense to not just change the origin of the transformation, and calculating it yourself would do the exact same thing, only a hundred times more complicated, you should really just add this to the CSS to solve the issue

```
-moz-transform-origin: 0 0;
-o-transform-origin: 0 0;
-webkit-transform-origin: 0 0;
transform-origin: 0 0;
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/y343Z/21/)

Just to confirm this, looking at MDN, at the bottom of the following pages, you'll find browser support, and it's just about the same for transform and transform-origin, as you generally never have one without the other

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-origin

As a final note, if it were me, I wouldn't even worry about IE8 and below, as those users are probably used to things looking weird these days anyway.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to use `transform-origin` you can do this :

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/chadocat/y343Z/13/)**

```
$(function () {
    var isScaled = false;
    $('#box').on('click', function () {
        if (isScaled) {
            isScaled = false;
            $(this).width('200').css({'top':'50px','left':'50px'})
        } else {
            isScaled = true;
            $(this).width('400').css({'top':'24px','left':'46px'});
        }
    })
});
```

Answer (score 3):

As other people has stated, you can use `transform-origin`. However, if you still want to do it via Javascript, I've done it for you in this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y343Z/33/).

Basically, what I do is to calculate the rotated position of the top left corners of each figure using the matrix transform for rotations (simplified), assuming the center point of the figures as `(0, 0)`, which is, basically, what the browser does. Once I calculate the new positions for the corners, I calculate the difference, and substract that difference from the original `left` and `top` positions. I hope you find it instructive.

```
$(function () {

    var isScaled = false;
    var box = $('#box');

    box.on('click', function () {
        if (isScaled) {
            isScaled = false;
            $(this).width('200');
            placeBox(400, 200);
        } else {
            isScaled = true;
            $(this).width('400')
            placeBox(200, 400);
        }    
    });
    var left = parseInt(box.css('left'));
    var top = parseInt(box.css('top'));
    var angle = (345 / 360) * 2 * Math.PI; //in radians;    

    function placeBox(oldWidth, newWidth) {
        var midHeight = box.height() / 2;
        var midOldWidth = oldWidth / 2;
        var midNewWidth = newWidth / 2;
        var cos = Math.cos(angle);
        var sin = Math.sin(angle);
        //rotation center coordinates
        var cx1 = left + midOldWidth;
        var cx2 = left + midNewWidth;
        var cy = top + midHeight;
        var mx1 = -midOldWidth * cos + midHeight * sin;
        var my1 = -midOldWidth * sin - midHeight * cos;
        var mx2 = -midNewWidth * cos + midHeight * sin;
        var my2 = -midNewWidth * sin - midHeight * cos;
        var difX = cx2 + mx2 - cx1 - mx1;
        var difY = my2 - my1;
        //now, position the element where it should:
        box.css({
            left: (left - difX) + 'px',
            top: (top - difY) + 'px'
        });
    }
})
```

Answer (score 2):

This Fiddle is showing the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/y343Z/19/ 
If you change the "shadow" size, it is moving alongside it's X Y axis.

Here one possibile soution.
http://jsfiddle.net/y343Z/18/

Just place shadow inside of the tranformed element:

```
<div id="box">
<div id="box-shadow" style="width:400px;"></div>
</div>
```

With this CSS:

```
#box {
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    position:absolute;
    top:50px;
    left:50px;
    -moz-transform:rotate(345deg);
    -webkit-transform:rotate(345deg);
    -o-transform:rotate(345deg);
    -ms-transform:rotate(345deg);
}
#box-shadow {
    width: inherit;
    height: inherit;
    background-color:silver;
    position:absolute;
    opacity: 0.3;
}
#box {
    background-color:orange;
    -ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=50)";
    filter: alpha(opacity=50);
    -moz-opacity: 0.5;
    -khtml-opacity: 0.5;
    opacity: 0.5;
}
```

Just to clarify: I know that is not desired for a real shadow, since this has to be outside of the transformed box. But i think your shadow object is a "helper" that contains handles like in your screenshot.

Edit:

As other user posted, you may also use transform-origin: http://jsfiddle.net/y343Z/20/

```
 transform-origin: left center 0;
```